# Reacting to a Signal in MVVM?

Tags: swift, mvvm, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa, rx-swift

While setting up a login view and using Reactive programming for my first time - I am having trouble generating a Signal from my ViewContoller that will alert my `observeValues` listener in my view with a Bool containing my form validation:

**View File**

```
viewModel.outputs.loginSuccess
    .observeValues { [weak self] value in
        print(value)
}
```

With my current code `loginSuccess` is firing every time the email or password text fields are changed (I have `.addTarget`'s in my View File that update my MutableProperites in My Model View file).  Where I am experiencing trouble is creating a signal for `tryLogin` that only emits when the login button is pressed, and then maps my form validation ( `emailAndPassword.map(isValid)` ), which I can respond to in my View File.

**Model View File**

```
import ReactiveCocoa
import ReactiveSwift
import Result

public protocol LoginViewModelInputs {

    /// String value of email textfield text
    func emailChanged(_ email: String?)

    /// String value of password textfield text
    func passwordChanged(_ password: String?)

    /// Call when login button is pressed.
    func loginButtonTapped()
}

public protocol LoginViewModelOutputs {

    /// Emits on login.
    var loginSuccess: Signal<(Bool), NoError> { get }
}

public protocol LoginViewModelType {
    var inputs: LoginViewModelInputs { get }
    var outputs: LoginViewModelOutputs { get }
}

public final class LoginViewModel: LoginViewModelType, LoginViewModelInputs,     LoginViewModelOutputs {

    public init() {

        let emailAndPassword = Signal.combineLatest(
            self.emailChangedProperty.signal.skipNil(),
            self.passwordChangedProperty.signal.skipNil()
        )

        let tryLogin = loginButtonTappedProperty.map {
            emailAndPassword.map(isValid)
        }

        self.loginSuccess = tryLogin.value
    }

    fileprivate let emailChangedProperty = MutableProperty<String?>(nil)
    public func emailChanged(_ email: String?) {
        self.emailChangedProperty.value = email
    }
    fileprivate let loginButtonTappedProperty = MutableProperty()
    public func loginButtonTapped() {
        self.loginButtonTappedProperty.value = ()
    }
    fileprivate let passwordChangedProperty = MutableProperty<String?>(nil)
    public func passwordChanged(_ password: String?) {
        self.passwordChangedProperty.value = password
    }

    public let loginSuccess: Signal<(Bool), NoError>

    public var inputs: LoginViewModelInputs { return self }
    public var outputs: LoginViewModelOutputs { return self }
}

func isValid(email: String, password: String) -> Bool {
    return !email.characters.isEmpty && !password.characters.isEmpty
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  I haven't found much good documentation to learn about Signals or Observers, but it's possible I haven't been looking in the right places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach that I would take

- Enable and disable the loginButton based on the validation of the username and password input
- Bind login action to button event

Here is the code:

```
let usernameField: UITextField
let passwordField: UITextField
let loginEnabled: MutableProperty<Bool>
let loginButton: UIButton

loginEnabled <~
    Signal.combineLatest(
        usernameField.reactive.controlEvents(.allEditingEvents),
        passwordField.reactive.controlEvents(.allEditingEvents))
    .map { _ -> Bool in
        return validation()
    }

// only allow button to be pressed when validation succeeds
loginButton.reactive.isEnabled <~ loginEnabled

// login action
let loginAction = Action<(String?,String?),Void,NoError> { (username, password) -> SignalProducer<Void, NoError> in
    // replace with login procedure
    return SignalProducer.empty
}

// bind button event to login action
loginButton.reactive.pressed = CocoaAction(loginAction, input: 
    (usernameField.text, passwordField.text))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/RACCommunity/RACNest/blob/master/Documents/1_form.md) is an example of an Input Form built with RAC.

Its a little bit outdated though - everything in this example that starts with `rex_` (which was an external extension library for UI Bindings which now is integrated directly into RAC) is now changed to `.reactive.`

- `UITextField.rex_textSignal` is now `UITextField.reactive.continuousTextValues`
- `UIButton.rex_pressed` is now `UIButton.reactive.pressed`

Instead of saving the credentials to `NSUserDefaults` in the `authenticationAction`, you would implement your actual authenticate action.

**BTW:** you should never save user credentials, especially passwords, to `NSUserDefaults`. Use the Keychain instead!

The Key-Points are

- Use `MutableProperty` in your viewModel to store the current input values
- Use the `.reactive` property on interface elements and the binding operator `<~` to bind your viewModel to the inputs (`viewModel.attribute <~ textField.reactive.continuouseTextValues`)
- Use `Action` to perform the actual work on demand
- Bind the `Action` to a UIControl via `CocoaAction` (`button.reactive.pressed = CocoaAction(viewModel.loginAction)`)

Hope that helps you!

Comment: thanks it does! I just wrote some saving user credential code yesterday and used the keychain ;)